# Angular js - как заменить переменную в виде массива json через ajax с БД

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

http://jsfiddle.net/rzgWr/19/ - demo

Создаю файл getdata.php

```
include 'db.php';
$sel = mysqli_query($link,"select * from products");
$data = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sel)) {
 $data[] = array("name"=>$row['name'],"shirt"=>$row['shirt'],"pants"=>$row['pants'],"shoes"=>$row['shoes']);
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

По ссылке в демо есть такой участок кода:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, filterFilter) {
    $scope.usePants = {};
    $scope.useShirts = {};
    $scope.useShoes = {};

    $scope.players = [
        {name: 'Bruce Wayne', shirt: 'XXL', pants: '42', shoes: '12'},
        {name: 'Wayne Gretzky', shirt: 'XL', pants: '38', shoes: '10'},
        {name: 'Michael Jordan', shirt: 'M', pants: '32', shoes: '9'},
        {name: 'Rodman', shirt: 'XSXL', pants: '42', shoes: '11'},
        {name: 'Jake Smitz', shirt: 'XXL', pants: '42', shoes: '12'},
        {name: 'Will Will', shirt: 'XXLL', pants: '42', shoes: '12'},
        {name: 'Youasdf Oukls', shirt: 'XL', pants: '38', shoes: '10'},
        {name: 'Sam Sneed', shirt: 'XL', pants: '38', shoes: '10'},
        {name: 'Bill Waxy', shirt: 'M', pants: '32', shoes: '9'},
        {name: 'Javier Xavior', shirt: 'M', pants: '32', shoes: '9'},
        {name: 'Bill Knight', shirt: 'M', pants: '32', shoes: '9'},        
        {name: 'One More', shirt: 'M', pants: '32', shoes: '9'},        
        {name: 'Player One', shirt: 'XXL', pants: '42', shoes: '11'},
        {name: 'Space Cadet', shirt: 'XXL', pants: '42', shoes: '12'},
        {name: 'Player Two', shirt: 'XXXXL', pants: '42', shoes: '12'}
    ];
```

Собственно вопрос, как переменную $scope.players = вывести через аякс запрос так, чтобы не нарушить эту работающую конструкцию?

Заменяю $scope.players на:

```
myApp.controller('playersCrtl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $http.get('getdata.php').success(function(data){
         $scope.players = data;
    });
```

Выводит ошибку:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>       at uniqueItems ((index):94)
>   Строка 94 :

```
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
```

Собственно, как правильно в имеющейся функции `function MyCtrl($scope, filterFilter) {`
вывести `$scope.players` через аякс?

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: так ошибка не связана-то с `$scope.players`. Вы на 94 строчке обращаетесь к полю length переменной  типа undefined.

Comment: связана, поскольку если оставить  $scope.players = [] как есть, то все работает замечательно. Только вывожу через аякс (не уверен, что правильно), сразу выскакивает эта ошибка. Я так понимаю как-то не правильно вытягиваю через запрос массив этот.

Comment: перед аяксом инициализируйте пустым массивом `$scope.players = []` потом попробуйте получить аяксом данные - это ваш  $http.get.

Comment: не получается, к сожалению. Та же ошибка.

Comment: откройте инспектор во вкладке networks и проверьте запрос. Правильно ли данные приходят

Comment: Данные никакие не приходят поскольку есть эта ошибка.

Comment: значит нужно инициализировать `$scope.players = []` в начале контроллера

Comment: $scope.players = [] должен быть сразу инициализирован пустым массивом по умолчанию.

Comment: function MyCtrl($scope, $http, filterFilter) {
    $scope.usePants = {};
    $scope.useShirts = {};
    $scope.useShoes = {};
$http.get("getdata.php").success(function(data){ 
         $scope.players = data; 
     });

Comment: сделал так, от части может что и не верно, но выводит все как надо, пока что))) ошибка в 94 строке так и осталась, но в итоге ни на что не влияет вроде как...

Comment: попробуйте перед 94 поставить $scope.players = []

Comment: поставил $scope.players = [] перед $http.get("getdata.php") - ошибка ушла. Спасибо. Когда через контроллер вызывал аякс и перед ставил $scope.players = [] - ошибка была. Нужно было видать в функцию только добавить переменную $http и без вызова контроллера внутри функции.